# Scala-Slick: only part of sequence of actions executed

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

Have a piece of code that adds/updates a Product and also associates one or more tags to it. Tags are actually added to a TagGroup and that is associated with the Product.

Issue I am facing is that only "part" of addOrUpdateProductWithTags() executes. Product is updated or created but Tags are not added. If I comment the last query (see comment) then everything works. Have turned on "" to confirm this.

```
lazy val pRetId = prods returning prods.map(_.id)

def addTags(keywords: Seq[String]) = {
  for {
    k <- keywords
  } yield {
    tags.filter(_.keyword === k).take(1).result.headOption.flatMap {
      case Some(tag) => { 
        Logger.debug("Using existing tag: " + k)  
        DBIO.successful(tag.id)
      }
      case None => {
        Logger.debug("Adding new tag: " + k)
        tags.returning(tags.map(_.id)) += Tag(k, Some("DUMMY")) 
      }
    } 
  }   
}

def addOrUpdateProductWithTags(prod: Product, tagSet: Seq[String]): Future[Option[Long]] = {

  // handle add or update product
  val prodObject = prod.id match {
    case 0L => pRetId += prod
    case _ => prods.withFilter(_.id === prod.id).update(prod)
  }

  val action = for {
    pid <- prodObject
    tids <- DBIO.sequence(addTags(tagSet))
  } yield (tids, pid)

  val finalAction = action.flatMap {
    case (tids, pid) => {
      val prodId = if (prod.id > 0L) prod.id else pid.asInstanceOf[Number].longValue
      val delAction = tagGroups.filter(_.prodId === prodId).delete
      val tgAction = for {
        tid <- tids
      } yield {
        tagGroups += TagGroup("Ignored-XX", prodId, tid)
      }
      delAction.flatMap { x => DBIO.sequence(tgAction) }

      // IF LINE BELOW IS COMMENTED THEN TagGroup is created else even delete above doesn't happen
      prods.filter(_.id === prodId).map(_.id).result.headOption
    }
  }

  db.run(finalAction.transactionally)
}
```

This is the snippet in the controller where this method is called from. My suspicion is that caller doesn't wait long enough but not sure...

```
val prod = Prod(...)
val tagSet = generateTags(prod.tags)
val add = prodsService.addOrUpdateProductWithTags(prod, tagSet)
add.map { value =>
  Redirect(controllers.www.routes.Dashboard.dashboard)
}.recover {
  case th => 
    InternalServerError("bad things happen in life: " + th)
}
```

Any clue what's wrong with the query ?
Stack: Scala 2.11.7, play version 2.5.4, play-slick 2.0.0 (slick 3.1)

Comment: have you tried printing the sql queries executed? `<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement"  level="DEBUG" />`

Comment: yes had done that, it doesn't show delete and following actions if the last line is present.

Comment: Could you show the contents of `addTags` ?

Comment: edited - also should add that this code was working sometime back for me, and suddenly I am seeing this behavior. Not sure what could have caused this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a solution:

In place of the following 2 lines:

```
    delAction.flatMap { x => DBIO.sequence(tgAction) }
    prods.filter(_.id === prodId).map(_.id).result.headOption
```

I combined the actions with andThen operators as follows:

```
    delAction >> DBIO.sequence(tgAction) >> prods.filter(_.id === prodId).map(_.id).result.headOption
```

Now the entire sequence gets executed. I still don't know what's wrong with the original solution but this works.

Comment: the sql queries u wanted to execute should be the last line in the  finalAction's flatMap i.e action.flatMap{}

Comment: last line will b returned as the finalAction